# Android Instrumentation Test Runner: How to filter multiple test annotations

Tags: android, testing, adb, instrumentation, android-instrumentation

The documentation for `instrument` is clear on how to filter a single test annotation from a test run:

> **Filter test run to tests without given annotation**: adb shell am instrument -w -e notAnnotation com.android.foo.MyAnnotation com.android.foo/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner

(from https://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/InstrumentationTestRunner.html)

Is it possible to filter multiple annotations? I have not found a syntax that works thus far. I have tried:

- `adb shell am instrument -w -e notAnnotation com.android.foo.MyAnnotation -e notAnnotation com.android.foo.AnotherAnnotation com.android.foo/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner`
- `adb shell am instrument -w -e notAnnotation com.android.foo.MyAnnotation,com.android.foo.AnotherAnnotation com.android.foo/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner`
- `adb shell am instrument -w -e notAnnotation com.android.foo.MyAnnotation com.android.foo.AnotherAnnotation com.android.foo/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner`
- `adb shell am instrument -w -e notAnnotation "com.android.foo.MyAnnotation","com.android.foo.AnotherAnnotation" com.android.foo/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner`

and probably others that I've forgotten, thus far to no avail.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Did you find out what was the problem? (Besides using InstrumentationTestRunner instead of AndroidJUnitRunner )

Answer (score 0):

You should be using [AndroidJUnitRunner](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/runner/AndroidJUnitRunner.html) anyway:

> **Filter test run to tests without any of a list of annotations:**
>
> adb shell am instrument -w -e notAnnotation com.android.foo.MyAnnotation,com.android.foo.AnotherAnnotation com.android.foo/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner